# Open .dly file (GHCN / NOAA data) for analysis

Tags: python, file-types

I am trying to work with the data available from: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/datasets and https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/hcn/

[image]

It comes in a .dly file.  Is there a way to open this with Python or Excel?

My ultimate goal is to have them in a file format that I can open with Python and Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

These are fixed-width format files - each column is a specific number of characters wide. You can read it with `pandas.read_fwf()`.

There is a `readme.txt` available at https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ for the GHCN data you linked, which includes a title, width and data type for each column. You can supply these to `read_fwf()` if the automatic width detection doesn't work. I think you have to add the column titles manually though.

**edit:** I have added an example snippet you can use at https://gitlab.com/snippets/1838910